# Why is $\frac{1}{|x|^{n-2}}u(\frac{x}{|x|^2})$ harmonic if $u$ is harmonic?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis

I found myself trying to prove the following, but I had to compute everything explicitly.

It is well known that if $u:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is an harmonic function on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the so-called Kelvin transform of $u$

$$(Ku)(x):=\frac{1}{|x|^{n-2}}u\biggl(\frac{x}{|x|^2}\biggr)$$

is harmonic in $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$.

Question: Is there a way to prove that $Ku$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ WITHOUT making the explicit computations?

I know that there are tricks to soften the calculations (for example noticing that $1/|x|^{n-2}$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$), however I wasn't able to find a "clever" way to do it. I noticed that $x\mapsto x/|x|^2$ is a special transformation but I wasn't able to go anywhere, not even using the mean value property.

Comment: This isn't just spherical inversion?  i.e. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3605490/how-to-show-laplaces-equation-is-invariant-to-spherical-inversion

Comment: @Buzz The spherical inversion you mentioned is for $n=3$ and here there is no restriction on the dimension.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz That question is concerned with $n=3$, but the Laplace equation is invariant under conformal transformations (like spherical inversion) in any number of dimensions, no?

Comment: @Buzz Conformal invariance only for $n=2$. Note that when $n=2$, $1/|x|^{n-2}=1$ so this is just an inversion in the sphere. If $n\geq 3$, existence of the factor $1/|x|^{n-2}$ means that this is not a simple reparametriczation using inversion in the sphere.

Comment: I think that the easiest way is to write the Laplacian in spherical coordinates. OIne needs the existence of the laplace beltrami, but not the explicit expression. Then rthe computation reduce only to radial derivatives. the

Comment: The same question has been [asked on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4553046/really-why-is-the-kelvin-transform-harmonic).

Comment: @TimothyBudd I know, he is a friend of mine and we decided to post it here as well to find an answer.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune What you are saying in any case implies an explicit computation. Although maybe correct, it is not what I am looking for. As I said in the post I have already solved this problem by computations (not with a change of coordinates, that is true).

Comment: Please edit your post. I downvoted erroneously and I cannot change.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97321/can-one-understand-the-kelvin-transform-conceptually . It's basically the first non-trivial example of the conformal invariance (with suitable weights) of the conformal Laplacian, which is the first in a hierarchy of conformally invariant operators that includes the Paneitz operator.  I think one can argue from abstract nonsense (representation theory?) that some sort of conformally invariant operator of this type should exist, though I don't see how to get precisely the Kelvin transform formula without at least some computation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An explanation can be the following. Take a harmonic function of the form $u(x)=r^\alpha P(\omega)$, with $r=|x|$, $|\omega|=1$ and $P$ a polynomial. Then $0=\Delta u=r^{\alpha-2}\left (\alpha(N-2+\alpha)P(\omega)+\Delta_S P(\omega)\right)$ with $\Delta_S$ the Laplace-Beltrami on the unit sphere $S$. Then $\Delta_S P=-\alpha(N-2+\alpha)P$. However we know that the eigenvalues of $\Delta_S$ are given by $-k(N-2+k)$ with $k$ a nonegative integer but the equation $\alpha(N-2+\alpha)=k(N-2+k)$ has another root $\alpha=2-N-k$ which corresponds to the Kelvin transform $Ku(x)=|x|^{2-N}u(x/|x|^2)$. This shows that $Ku$ is harmonic whenever $u$ is an harmonic polynomial and then (approximating locally) for any harmonic function $u$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another explanation which has various generalizations.

Denote by $L = \Delta + \frac{n-2}{4(n-1)}R$ the [conformal Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operators_in_differential_geometry#Conformal_Laplacian) of a Riemannian manifold $(M^n,g)$ (my convention is that $\Delta$ is a nonnegative operator).  If $\Phi \colon M \to M$ is a conformal diffeomorphism — i.e. $\Phi^\ast g = e^{2\phi}g$ for some $\phi \in C^\infty(M)$ — then
$$ (Lu) \circ \Phi = e^{-\frac{n+2}{2}\phi} L\left( e^{\frac{n-2}{2}\phi} (u \circ \Phi) \right) . $$

Let's now specialize to $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $g$ the Euclidean metric. Then $\Phi(x) := x/\lvert x \rvert^2$ is a conformal diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$ with $\Phi^\ast g = \lvert x \rvert^{-4} g$. Therefore

$$ (\Delta u)\left( \frac{x}{\lvert x\rvert^2}\right) = \lvert x \rvert^{n+2} \Delta \left( \lvert x \rvert^{2-n} u \bigl( \frac{x}{\lvert x\rvert^2} \bigr) \right) $$
for any $u \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\})$.
Specializing to the case when $u$ is harmonic recovers your result.

One generalization of this is the following:
There is a [family](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Conformally_invariant_operators) of operators $L_{2\gamma} = \Delta^\gamma + \mathrm{l.o.t.}$, $\gamma \in (0 , n/2]$, on $(M^n,g)$ such that if $\Phi^\ast g = e^{2\phi}g$, then
$$ \tag{$\ast$} \label{eqn} (L_{2\gamma}u) \circ \Phi = e^{-\frac{n+2\gamma}{2}\phi} L_{2\gamma}\left( e^{\frac{n-2\gamma}{2}\phi} (u \circ \Phi) \right) . $$
On Euclidean space, $L_{2\gamma} = \Delta^\gamma$, so one concludes that if $u \in \ker \Delta^\gamma$, then $\lvert x\rvert^{2\gamma-n}u\bigl( x/\lvert x\rvert^2 \bigr) \in \ker \Delta^\gamma$.

While there are relatively simple proofs of \eqref{eqn}, they all require developing a fair bit of machinery besides doing a direct computation in Euclidean space by some other mechanism.